# Storing procedure in environment of evaluator leads to infinite loop

Tags: clojure, scheme, evaluation, sicp

I converted the [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1) version of the meta-circular evaluator to Clojure. The main difference (besides syntax) is the handling of the environment structure. Since you cannot use `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` in Clojure, these are implemented via an atom holding a map (copied from the code of [Greg Sexton's chapter 4 notes on GitHub](https://github.com/gregsexton/SICP-Clojure/blob/master/src/sicp/ch4.clj), which I believe has the same problem with not being able to define a procedure).

The code of the two evaluators can be found here:

- [SICP Evaluator Scheme](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/code/ch4-mceval.scm)
- [Converted Evaluator Clojure](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/1dd7e9cba93bc8e4e3255ac8cd48ba9f)

Unfortunately defining a procedure does not work properly. What I expect to happen is this:

> ;;; M-Eval input:
>   (defn (add1 x) (+ x 1))
>   ;;; M-Eval value:
>   < Environment printed > 
>   ;;; M-Eval input:
>   (add1 10)
>   ;;; M-Eval value:
>   11

<sub>Note: it is basically Scheme code that is entered except for define which is called defn.</sub>

Here defining `add1` stores a procedure in the environment structure and when it is called with `(add1 10`) the symbol `add1` is looked up in the environment and the procedure created by the evaluator is applied to 10, resulting in 11.

What I see however is this:

> ;;; M-Eval input:
>   (defn (add1 x) (+ x 1))
>   ;;; M-Eval value:
>   {add1 (procedure (x) (((+ x 1))) (#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x7c197838 {:status :ready, :val {add1 (procedure (x) (((+ x 1))) (#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x7c197838 {:status :ready, :val {add1 (procedure (x) (((+ x 1))) (#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x7c197838 {:status :ready, :val {add1 (procedure (x) (((+ x 1))) (#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x7c197838 {:status :ready, :val {add1 (procedure (x) (((+ x 1))) (... et cetera)

I get a very long environment output (**it looks like the created procedure has an environment that contains the procedure itself**) and then a StackOverflowError.

> 2. Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
>      Error compiling:
>      scheme-evaluator.clj:316:1
>      (...)
> 3. Caused by java.lang.StackOverflowError
>      (No message)

For clarity, I put the `eval` below. But I think [the whole code](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/1dd7e9cba93bc8e4e3255ac8cd48ba9f) needs to be run to properly see what is wrong.

```
(defn eval [exp env]
  (cond (self-evaluating? exp) exp
        (variable? exp) (lookup-variable-value exp env)
        (quoted? exp) (text-of-quotation exp)
        (assignment? exp) (eval-assignment exp env)
        (definition? exp) (eval-definition exp env)
        (if? exp) (eval-if exp env)
        (lambda? exp) (make-procedure (lambda-parameters exp) 
                                      (lambda-body exp)
                                      env)
        (begin? exp) (eval-sequence (begin-actions exp) env)
        (cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env)
        (application? exp) (apply (eval (operator exp) env)
                                  (list-of-values (operands exp) env))
        :else (throw (Throwable. (str "Unknown expression type \"" exp "\" -- EVAL")))))
```

I hope someone can help me with this and perhaps shine some light on what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `lambda-body` procedure. The `lambda` list contains 3 elements; tag, parameters and its body. However retrieving the body by `lambda-body` uses `cddr` instead of `caddr`, thus the result get wrapped by extra list. So if you change the definition of `lambda-body` like this:

```
(defn lambda-body [exp] (third exp))
```

then you can get result computed.

NB: if you want to avoid stack overflow error, then you can change `eval-definition` or `define-variable!` to return something else such as name of the given `exp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. `cddr` is also used in the Scheme implementation. It is retrieved via `third` in `procedure-body`. I believe this to be correct. And holy moly, you are right! Apparently Clojure returns the last value automatically. If I change the last definition in `eval-definition` to `'()` the environment works fine!!! Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Ai, although it solves the problem described above. The code still gets into the infinite loop when calling a procedure in a lambda expression: `;;; Eval input: (defn test (fn () scope)) ;;; Eval value: test defined ;;; Eval input: ((fn (scope) (test)) (quote dynamic-scope))`.

Comment: Or just `(defn first (fn () "FIRST"))`, and then `(defn second-first (fn () (first))`. So executing the first function in the second leads to the endless environment structure printed.

Comment: Or when defining a procedure with the same name twice. :)